# Data from dynamically added parsed textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a simple calculator to save myself from having to add up a bunch of invoice totals on basic calculator at work (since we use paper invoices). I'm just getting the basic functionalities in place currently and one of the functions I have is adding extra textboxes and then later trying to add all of the values in the textboxes to a subtotal. The problem I am having (I think) is that the compiler needs to have the the textbox ID's before the program is compiled. I'm also going to apologize for the sloppy variable names, I tried everything I could think of in my basic mindset until 4AM and by the time I was just using any variable. I've tried all the iterations, (ended up with do while statement as you can see).

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int partboxes = 3;
        int lastY = 83;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonFinal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddParts();
        }

        public double AddParts()
        {
            int i = 1;
            double megavalue = 0;


            do
            {
                double totalsum = double.Parse(("partBox" + i).Text);
                megavalue = totalsum + megavalue;

                i = i + 1;
            } while (i < partboxes);


            string supervalue = megavalue.ToString();
            lblPartsTotal.Text = supervalue;
            return megavalue;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox partBox = new TextBox();
            partBox.Name = "partBox" + partboxes++;
            partBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, lastY + 26);
            partBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            // Add the textbox control to the form's control collection
            this.Controls.Add(partBox);
            lastY = lastY + 26;
            partboxes = partboxes++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using a spreadsheet or the history feature in the calculator?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a textbox by name from the `Controls` property with

```
var tb = (TextBox)Controls["partBox" + i];
```

where `i` is the textbox number.

The indexer returns a `Control`. But since every control has a `Text` property, you can use it without casting.

```
double totalsum = double.Parse(Controls["partBox" + i].Text);
```

See: [Control.ControlCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2)